# mysql grant GRANT_OPTION and CREATE_USER

Tags: mysql

Im trying to create a user which only have some priviligies.

First log into mysql

`* mysql -u root -p
Server version: 5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.10.1`

Create the user

`* CREATE USER 'createuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'createuser';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)`

Now I want to grant the priviligies

`* GRANT CREATE, GRANT_OPTION, CREATE_USER, RELOAD ON *.* TO 'createuser'@'%';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GRANT_OPTION, CREATE_USER, RELOAD ON *.* TO 'createuser'@'%'' at line 1`

So I splitted the commando into 4

`* GRANT CREATE ON *.* TO 'createuser'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)`

`* GRANT GRANT_OPTION ON *.* TO 'createuser'@'%';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GRANT_OPTION ON *.* TO 'createuser'@'%'' at line 1`

`* GRANT CREATE_USER ON *.* TO 'createuser'@'%';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE_USER ON *.* TO 'createuser'@'%'' at line 1`

`* GRANT RELOAD ON *.* TO 'createuser'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)`

So what is the commando to grant [CREATE_USER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-user) and [GRANT_OPTION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_grant-option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the underscores and it'll work.

Answer (score -1):

**grant create user on database_name.table_name to root_user with grant option;**

**Flush Privileges;**

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.